# NoReverseMatch in django production server

Tags: django, django-urls

The project is working fine in the dev server but when I try to use it in the production sv(Gunicorn + Nginx), NoReverseMatch error appears. I checked the code several times and I can't find the error.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^obras/', include('obras.urls')),
)
```

obras urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from obras import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^presobra/$', views.pres_obra, name='pres_obra'), 
)
```

Error message:

Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8888/admin/

Python Path:
     ['/srv/www/antingprojects.com.ar/gobras',
     ...
     ']

Exception Value:
 Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'pres_obra' with arguments '()' and  keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Template error

In template /srv/www/antingprojects.com.ar/gobras/templates/admin/index.html, error at line  75
 Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'pres_obra' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

```
75      <li><a href={% url pres_obra %}>Presupuestos-Obras</a></li>
```

settings.py:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'gobras.urls'
```

Project structure:

```
-gobras
--obras
--media
```

Comment: Please post the the actual error message.

Comment: I'm having a similar error; one weird thing is if I use gunicorn_django, it works, but if I use gunicorn I get this error. My python path also includes my application, so I don't think it's a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: from obras.urls import urlpatterns as obras_urlpatterns to the urls.py.  I'll bet that it fails, and that the issue is the PYTHONPATH in production isn't finding the obras app.  Make sure you have it set correctly.